# What's the easiest way to make a real-time chatting app with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a real-time chatting app with Xamarin and some kind of backend technology. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I have a better solution.  The above-mentioned technologies(buddy SDK & SignalR) will require you to integrate and handle everything by your self. Instead, you can go for CometChat SDK, which has real-time chat along with Audio/Video chat functionalities. Also, you can use its ready-made UI inside your application. It is the easiest & quickest way for you to make a real-time chatting system. For more information on CometChat you can refer to the following link:

https://developer.cometchat.com/docs/xamarin-forms-quick-start

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by ChristiaanV, SignalR is the way to go.
The Performance is great with Xamarin, we delivered more than 150k messages within 2 hours without any problems regarding the connection.
With Azure Mobile App and ServiceBus, you can easily scale out your backend, as described here http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SignalR, it's a good and easy to use framework to do realtime 'things'. They also have a Xamarin Component which is free to use.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

http://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr

Please note that I personally don't have experience with using it on mobile devices, so I can't tell you anything about how it's performing battery / performance wise.